# JQuery can't bind paste event to dynamic content

Tags: jquery, paste

I am trying to bind the paste event to dynamic content in asp.net using jquery.  I've tried both `live()` and `on()` and neither work with the paste event.  I can get events like keydown working fine.  I can also use `bind()` to bind the paste event and it fires, but I need it to work for dynamic content as well.

Below is an example of what I am trying:

```
    $(".NumericOnly").on('paste', function (evt) {
        alert('here');
    });
```

Again, if I change the on to blur, it works, but not for dynamic content.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".NumericOnlyParent").on('paste', '.NumericOnly', function (evt) {
    alert('here');
});
```

I'm making up `.NumericOnlyParent`. Replace it with `.NumericOnly`'s parent.

Learn more here: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: This is intended to be a generic function for all numeric input fields, so the parent will be different for most controls.

Comment: Then try `$(document).on(...`.